# django forms and filtering

Tags: python, django, query-string, filtering

So i have this jobs select form that should allow a user to:

1) select a filterBy set of radio buttons.  This lets the user select which method he wants to filter a list by.  (this will perform a GET with a 'filterBy' query string

2) allow a user to filter the list by an object from a comobox that is the result of #1.  This form performs a POST with the 'filter' set to the pk of a filterBy object

Here is the code i have:

```
selectForm = JobSelectForm()
filterByForm = FilterByForm()
filterForm = FilterForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    #this works just fine
    if 'job' in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/portal/jobs/%s/"%(request.POST['job']))

    if 'filter' in request.POST:
        filterForm = FilterForm(initial = {'filter': request.POST['filter']})

        ###### The Problem is below here
        ###### I cant get the 'filterBy' query string 
        ###### because this is a POST and not a GET
        ###### Is there a better way to write this filtering?

        if request.GET['filterby'] == 'G':
            obj = Group.objects.get(pk=request.POST['filter'])
            selectForm.fields['job'].queryset = Job.objects.filter(group=obj).order_by('name')
        elif request.GET['filterby'] == 'H':
            obj = Host.objects.get(pk=request.POST['filter'])
            selectForm.fields['job'].queryset = Job.objects.filter(host=obj).order_by('name')
        elif request.GET['filterby'] == 'L':
            obj = Location.objects.get(pk=request.POST['filter'])
            selectForm.fields['job'].queryset = Job.objects.filter(colo=obj).order_by('name')

###### All of this works fine too
elif request.method == 'GET':
    if request.GET.has_key('filterby'):
        if request.GET['filterby']:
            filterByForm = FilterByForm(initial = {'filterby': request.GET['filterby']})
            if request.GET['filterby'] == 'G':
                filterForm.fields['filter'].queryset = Group.objects.all().order_by('name')
            elif request.GET['filterby'] == 'H':
                filterForm.fields['filter'].queryset = Host.objects.all().order_by('name')
            elif request.GET['filterby'] == 'L':
                filterForm.fields['filter'].queryset = Location.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

Comment: Why separate GET and POST?  Why not just use GET and make this simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.REQUEST` (see: [Django Request and Response Objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/)). It holds the values of both `request.POST` and `request.GET`.

Also, when using dictionaries in Python, you should always verify that the key you're trying to access exists. This can be done in one of two ways:

1) Explicitly test for key in dictionary

```
if request.GET.has_key('filterby') and request.GET['filterby'] == 'G':
    obj = Group.objects.get(pk=request.POST['filter'])
    selectForm.fields['job'].queryset = Job.objects.filter(group=obj).order_by('name')
```

2) Use the dictionary's `get` method

```
if request.GET.get('filterby') == 'G':
    obj = Group.objects.get(pk=request.POST['filter'])
    selectForm.fields['job'].queryset = Job.objects.filter(group=obj).order_by('name')
```

With `dict.get` you can also pass a default value:

```
if request.GET.get('filterby', valueIfKeyDoesntExist) == 'G':
    obj = Group.objects.get(pk=request.POST['filter'])
    selectForm.fields['job'].queryset = Job.objects.filter(group=obj).order_by('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your problematic code in form's overrided `__init__` method.